# knex migration creat type for enum thows type already exists

Tags: postgresql, migration, database-migration, knex.js

I'm trying to alter a column in a table to modify knex enum to native types to benefit of the type system of Postgres, when I perform the migration I get this error  type `"request_type" already exists`, any idea what's happening here ?

```
export async function up(knex: Knex): Promise<any> {
  return knex.schema.alterTable('appointments', table => {
    table.enu('type', ['video', 'physical'], { useNative: true, enumName: 'request_type' }).alter();
  });
}

export async function down(knex: Knex): Promise<any> {
  return knex.schema
    .alterTable('appointments', table => {
      table.dropColumn('type');
    })
    .then(() => knex.raw('CREATE TYPE request_type AS ENUM("video", "physical")'))
    .then(() => knex.raw('drop type request_type'));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like there is a bug in knex which causes create type query to be added twice when altering columns like that.

https://runkit.com/embed/xqtl8p2knhi8

```
const Knex = require('knex');

const knex = Knex({
  client: 'pg',
});

knex.schema.alterTable('appointments', table => {
    table.enu('type', ['video', 'physical'], { useNative: true, enumName: 'request_type' }).alter();
}).toSQL()

/*
  Creates SQL:

0: Object {bindings: [], sql: "create type \"request_type\" as enum ('video', 'physical')"}
1: Object {bindings: [], sql: "create type \"request_type\" as enum ('video', 'physical')"}
2: Object {bindings: [], sql: "alter table \"appointments\" alter column \"type\" drop default"}
3: Object {bindings: [], sql: "alter table \"appointments\" alter column \"type\" drop not null"}
4: Object {bindings: [], …}
*/
```

Comment: I still have this error. Does anyone know a fix or a workaround for this?

Comment: At least common workaround for anything with knex is to write raw SQL statement instead of using the query builder method that didn't do the thing you wanted. `knex.schema.raw('alter table "appointments" <your preferred query> ....')`

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it. You can create the type on the fly.

Let's say the I want to create a product column and to use "product" enum as its allowed values. We can use this query:

```
table.enu('product', ['level1', 'level2'], { useNative: true, enumName: 'product' })
```

This will create the type on the fly and will create a column with this enum type